# Compatibility between protobuf 2.3.0 and 2.6.0

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm working with two sets of protobuf bindings, A and B.

A has been generated with protoc version **2.3.0** and B has been generated with protoc version **2.6.0**.  In my application that uses both of the above I'm using the `protobuf-java` library version **2.6.0**.

With this setup I get the following kind of error when interacting with A protobuf bindings:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Generated message class "A$Builder" missing method "getAMessageBuilder"
```

There are plenty of posts and questions about backwards compatibility between protobuf schemas, but what about library versions?  Are there any guarantees between protobuf versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protobuf for Java supports running older generated code against a newer runtime library and also mixing generated code from different compiler versions. However, this support only exists starting from version 3.0 (see the change log entry [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/17cc42a45aeab0f78a137fa6be6c36095db32e58/CHANGES.txt#L110)). So in your case it would probably be best to upgrade to 3.0 (or higher) if possible and regenerate your code with the 3.0 `protoc`, but after that one-time step you will no longer need to worry about regenerating your code as you update the protobuf library version.